# Spring server send realtime Objects to client

Tags: java, angularjs, spring, websocket, rickshaw

I have a question.

I got a Spring server and a Client (Angularjs). 
In my client i got a Rickshaw realtime chart.

When my server get some objects from a 3rd party software, i need it to send it to the client. This happens each 28th seconds.

I tried with websocket, and with SSE and i cannot get it to work.
I need someone to point me at a direction, since im lost atm.

Example.

Our server got a class called Animal. 
Then a 3rd party software is sending a new object of Animal (E.g dog-cat) each 28th second. 
When the server retrieves this object it, insert it in the DB and send it to the client. 
The last part is what i can't make work.

Websocket tryout:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
public class WebSocketConfig extends AbstractWebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry config){
        config.enableSimpleBroker("/MashData/data");
        config.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app");
    }

    @Override
    public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry){
        registry.addEndpoint("/mashData").setAllowedOrigins("*").withSockJS();
    }
}
```

And in my controller

```
@MessageMapping("/mashData")
@SendTo("/MashData/data")
@Async
public MashData insertData(@PathVariable Long id, @RequestBody MashData INCmashData){
         *Data created here*
         return insertData
        }
```

Comment: Do you have some basic code to share re WebSockets? That should do the trick so long as the browser understands WebSockets

Comment: As i just edited, my websocket arent responding with the correct data. And can't send a object each 28th seconds. Its just sending one object and thats it. I may note that this is my first encounter with websockets.

Comment: Well obviously that won't work. The `@MessageMapping` is only for mapping incoming requests, the `@sendTo` is for the result of a method, as your method returns `void` nothing will ever be sent. You will have to return the data created or put it on the queue manually yourself.

Comment: @M.Deinum That was an error from my side. I revoked my code when i tried SSE. But as i edited now, when i tried Websocket, i returned the created data. Yet nothing was returned.